# Let as a parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know why that isn't working:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let key = 123
    let class = Class(key: self.key)

}
```

and in the class my init looks like that:

```
init(let key: Int) {
    self.key = key
}
```

Is there a way to solve that. I know that `key: 123` as a parameter works but there must be another solution.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? using let in an `init` is not allowed and unnecessary. Parameters are passed as constants by default. I believe `inout` is the only alternative

Comment: Are your first 2 lines of code part of another class?  If so, you can't use `self` in the initialization of `class` because `self` isn't available until the object has been initialized.

Comment: You can do this: `private static let key = 123`, and then `let class = Class(key: ViewController.key)`.

Comment: Thanks, but is there another way to solve that issue without static or just with static?

Comment: You can do this `lazy var class = Class(key: self.key)`.  This lazily initializes class the first time it is accessed.  At that time, you will be able to use `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `self` in the inline initialization of a property because `self` isn't available until the object has been initialized.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let key = 123
    let class = Class(key: self.key)

}
```

You can either make `key` `static`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private static let key = 123
    let class = Class(key: ViewController.key)

}
```

or use `lazy` initialization of `class`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let key = 123
    lazy var class = Class(key: self.key)

}
```

This works because `class` isn't initialized until it is accessed, and at that time `ViewController` will be initialized and `self` will be available.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is simply function parameters can no longer be declared `let`. This change was part of SE-0003, which (in its adopted form) removed support for `var` parameters. Since parameters cannot be declared `var`, there is no particular reason to allow them to be explicitly declared `let`.

The final adopted form of SE-0003 was announced by Chris Lattner on [Jan 28, 2016 on the swift-evolution mailing list](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160125/008145.html). Here's the relevant section, with emphasis added:

> Parameter Lists
>
> ‘var’ in a parameter list is problematic for a number of reasons:
>
> - Parameter lists currently allow both “inout” and “var”, and real confusion occurs for some people learning swift that expect “var” to
>     provide reference semantics.
> - Parameter lists are not “patterns” in the language, so neither “let” nor “var” really make sense there.  Parameters were patterns in a much
>     older swift design, but that was eliminated a long time ago and this
>     aspect never got reconsidered.
> - “var” in a parameter list is odd because it is an implementation detail being foisted on the interface to the function.  To be fair, we
>     already have this with "API names" vs "internal names”, but this is a
>     bigger semantic implementation detail.
>
> **Conclusion: The core team decided that we should REMOVE “var” and
>   “let” from parameter lists.**
>
> “var” in a parameter list is convenient sugar that defines away some
>   minor boilerplate (the shadowing copy), however, the cost benefit
>   tradeoff doesn’t pay enough to keep it.

Comment: Ok, I remove the `let` in the init method but I still get the following error: Instance member cannot be used on type "ViewController"

Comment: `ViewController` doesn't appear in your question. If you edit your question to include your real code, we might be able to give better help.

Comment: In my example, I want to access the `Class` from the `ViewController`. The init method is in the class and the two lines above in the ViewController

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code and error message. Are the erroneous lines in a method, or in the main body of the `ViewController` class?

Comment: In the main body and @vacawama gave me a working solution above

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help!